# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: selector is different sometimes

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I have a problem with my iframe. Sometimes driver manage to enter iframe, sometimes not. When it fails, the following message appears:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="braintree-hosted-field-number"]"}

From what I see sometimes, selector is different but I can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
    def enter_new_credit_card(self):
     self.driver.switch_to('braintree-hosted-field-number')
     self.credit_card_number_field.send_keys('378282246310005')
     self.driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

And in my driver file I have following:

```
    def switch_to(self, element):
      return self.driver.switch_to.frame(element)

    def switch_to_default_content(self):
      return self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

HTML of the frame:

```
<iframe src="https://assets.braintreegateway.com/web/3.76.4/html/hosted-fields-frame.min.html" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" type="number" name="braintree-hosted-field-number" title="Secure Credit Card Frame - Credit Card Number" id="braintree-hosted-field-number" style="border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; float: left;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you using explicit wait?

Comment: yes I used sleep(5) most of the time but if fails with that sometimes

Comment: Post the `HTML` of iframe

Comment: @NandanA i have edited the question with HTML of the frame. Thank you!

Comment: do you have a link to the web-page so I can have a look? its hard to tell what the error is without seeing the page

Answer (score 0):

Try like below once:
And it would be better apply this in a `try` `except` block.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@title,'Secure Credit Card Frame')]")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```